# swing: saving dialog box resize dimensions

Tags: swing, dialog, persistence, jtable

I have a dialog box with a bunch of dimensions that a user can change by moving/dragging, including a JTable with resizable/draggable columns.

What I would like to do is to make the state of these resizable columns / dialog boxes / etc. persistent, so the next time my application starts up, the user doesn't have to go through the resizing step all over again.

What's the most convenient way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just add a PropertyChangeListener and save the Dimension every time the size was changed?

Comment: oh... well, detecting it is one thing, actually figuring out how/where to save the information is another. (and does PropertyChangeListener get a whole series of events as the user is dragging the mouse to continuously resizing columns, or does it only get 1 event at the end when the mouse button is released?)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably take a look at the code in (the now probably dead) JSR-296. A part of it was focused on persistent session state, and I know for sure that the code for persisting window locations and such was already functional and in the basic framework. It should either already do what you want, or provide a good starting point.

Cfr. [dev.java.net site for JSR-296](https://appframework.dev.java.net/)